# python PostgreSQL unit test not completing execution

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, nose

I have unit test as

```
class TestUser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print 'setting db up'
        db.create_all()

    def test_new_user(self):
        user = User('test_new_user@none.com', 'welcome')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        users_in_db = User.query.all()
        self.assertEquals(1, len(users_in_db))
        self.assertEquals(user.email, users_in_db[0].email)
        self.assertEquals(user._password, users_in_db[0]._password)
    def tearDown(self):
        print 'destroying db'
        db.drop_all()
```

When I run this on command-line, I see

```
python -m unittest discover
secret key: test secret key
db url: postgresql+psycopg2://testuser:testpasswd@localhost/mydb
setting db up
destroying db
```

But it never comes out, keep on hanging, what is that I am doing wrong?
I am new to unit testing in python and dont know how to test when I have to connect to database. Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for some time and looking around, the following started to work for me.
Its inefficient since it drops all table and creates them again for each tests, but for now as per the use case, it is fine and optimization will be added later.

As well said by Donald Knuth

> "premature optimization is root cause of all evil"

```
class TestUser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def session_commit(self):
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
        finally:
            pass

    def test_new_user(self):
        """
        test that new user is persisted in database
        """
        user = User('test_new_user@none.com', 'welcome')
        db.session.add(user)
        self.session_commit()
        users_in_db = db.session.query(User).all()
        self.assertEquals(1, len(users_in_db))
        self.assertEquals(user.email, users_in_db[0].email)
        self.assertEquals(user._password, users_in_db[0]._password)

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.close()
        for tbl in reversed(db.metadata.sorted_tables):
            db.engine.execute(tbl.delete())
```